# При получении значения из Entry выскакивает ошибка

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

У меня есть программа которая рассчитывает индекс массы тела. При получении значения из Entry выскакивает ошибка: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '' не подскажете?

Вот код:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

label1 = Label(text="Введите вес (кг):")
weight = Entry(root)

label2 = Label(text="Введите рост (см):")
height = Entry(root)

w = int(weight.get())
h = int(height.get())

print(w)
print(h)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас поля `Entry` не заполнены, поэтому при запросе значения из них вернулись пустые строки (`''`), что привело к ошибке при попытке привести их к числу.

Вам нужно проверять значения, например, через отлов исключения, что будет выброшено из `int`, если переданная в него строка не может быть конвертирована в число.

В качестве примера добавил кнопку при нажатии на которую будет выполняться получение значения из `weight` и `height` с приведением их к числу и проверкой.

Пример:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox


def on_button_clicked():
    try:
        w = int(weight.get())
        h = int(height.get())

    except ValueError:
        messagebox.showwarning("Warning", 'Поля вес и рост должны быть заполнены числами')
        return

    print(w)
    print(h)


root = Tk()

label1 = Label(text="Введите вес (кг):")
weight = Entry(root)

label2 = Label(text="Введите рост (см):")
height = Entry(root)

button = Button(root, text="Ok", command=on_button_clicked)

label1.pack()
weight.pack()
label2.pack()
height.pack()
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное

Answer (score 2):

У вас изначально пустая строка при вводе, поэтому и ошибка конвертации в int. То есть как такового ввода, в данном примере, нет.
Это равносильно тому, что я напишу код ниже и попытаюсь его запустить:

```
print(int(' '))
```

Comment: В этом коде же непустая строка

Comment: @dIm0n изначально она пуста. Дело в том, что даже запроса на ввод данных нет. Никакого input(), никаких элементов управления.

Comment: Я про код `print(int(' '))`, должно быть `print(int(''))` по идее

Comment: Хорошо спасибо, но как задать базовое значение для Entry?

Comment: @dIm0n да без разницы, ошибка всё равно будет.

Comment: Я просто новичок в python

Comment: @the_max_new тогда изучите для начала основы. Я так понимаю - это библиотека для создания каких-то оконных приложений (я с таковой не работал). Не думаю, что это отличный старт для новичков.

Comment: Ну я как бы прошел курс по python но там не было рассказано как указать базовое значение так что я знаю питон уже где-то 2 месяца

Comment: Просто я не могу назвать себя профи

Comment: @the_max_new вот, почитайте https://younglinux.info/tkinter/tkinter.php

Comment: Спасибо огромное!